# Why FloatingActionButton not working correctly with Get.showSnackbar(snackBar)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

when I use Flutter Getx Get.showSnackbar, FloatingActionButton is not working right. FloatingActionButton  does not move up or down.

Flutter Version:
[3.7.6]

Getx Version:
4.6.5

when I use FloatingActionButton with normal snackbar, FloatingActionButton slides up while snackbar slides up, but when used with Get.showSnackbar, FloatingActionButton doesn't slide up or even stays behind Snackbar invisible. is there a solution to this?